# iphone - how to disable network power saving mode

Tags: iphone, networking

Whilst making a Game Center GKMatch game I've come to realise the iphone networking hardware will go into power save mode if I don't transmit/receive anything within 100ms (or something like that). Coming out of power save mode can take 500ms, which is bad. To prevent this from happening I just send something periodically. But I don't REALLY want to do that because it uses up people's monthly 3G data usage.

Is there some way to programmatically disable power saving for networking?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this, but can you send something to localhost (`127.0.0.1`) periodically, to keep the connection up, without going over WWAN or wi-fi?

Comment: Ok you'll have to pretend I don't know how to do what you suggested :) I grabbed this example and it made no difference http://dev.im.ethz.ch/wiki/Socket_communication_on_the_iPhone. BTW I used "127.0.0.1" for the IP and 12345 for the port.

Comment: So can anyone explain what I need to do to try the above? A code snip would be most awesome.